# What does this notation about quadratic variation mean? $ [X]_t= X_0+ [X]_t^c + \sum_{0\leq s \leq t} \Delta X(s)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $(X_t)$ be a semimartingale. I read that its quadratic variation can be written as

$$ [X]_t= X_0+ [X]_t^c + \sum_{0\leq s \leq t} (\Delta X(s))^2$$

What does $[X]_t^c$ mean ? Is it the quadratic variation of $(X_t)$ if it was continuous, i.e the quadratic variation of $X_t - \sum_{0\leq s \leq t} \Delta X(s)$? I don't believe this to be true since we would need to assume that $\sum_{0\leq s \leq t} |\Delta X(s)|$ is finite, which is not the case for all semimartingales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how [Protter](https://www.amazon.ca/Stochastic-Integration-Differential-Equations-Protter/dp/3642055605/ref=sr_1_1?crid=33XZW4AO1HY38&keywords=Protter%20stochastic&qid=1668821073&qu=eyJxc2MiOiIwLjMyIiwicXNhIjoiMC4wMCIsInFzcCI6IjAuMDAifQ%3D%3D&sprefix=protter%20stochastic%20%2Caps%2C125&sr=8-1)  defines $\left[X\right]^c_t$ (Section II.6):

**Definition:** For a semimartingale $X$ the process  $\left[X\right]^c_t$ denotes path-by-path continuous part of  $\left[X\right]$.

---

Note that analogously, one can define $[X, Y]^c$ as the path-by-path continuous part of $[X, Y]$.